# Statistics on cluster member relationships over several days

Tags: r, statistics, time-series, cluster-analysis, k-means

Assume, I have hourly data corresponding to 5 categories for consective 10 days, created as:

```
library(xts)
set.seed(123)
timestamp <- seq(as.POSIXct("2016-10-01"),as.POSIXct("2016-10-10 23:59:59"), by = "hour")
data <- data.frame(cat1 = rnorm(length(timestamp),150,5),
                         cat2 = rnorm(length(timestamp),130,3),
                         cat3 = rnorm(length(timestamp),150,5),
                         cat4 = rnorm(length(timestamp),100,8),
                         cat5 = rnorm(length(timestamp),200,15))
data_obj <- xts(data,timestamp) # creat time-series object
head(data_obj,2)
```

Now, for each day separately, I perform clustering and see how these categories behave with respect to each other using simple `kmeans` as:

```
daywise_data <- split.xts(data_obj,f="days",k=1) # split data day wise
clus_obj <- lapply(daywise_data, function(x){ # clustering day wise
  return (kmeans(t(x), 2))
})
```

Once clustering is over, I visualize the cluster relationships over different 10 days with

```
sapply(clus_obj,function(x) x$cluster) # clustering results
```

and I found the results as

[image]

On visual inspection, it is clear that `cat1` and `cat3` always remained in the same cluster. Similarly `cat4` and `cat5` are mostly in different clusters on 10 different days.

Apart from visual inspection, **is there any automatic approach to gather this type of statistic from such clustering tables**?

---

Note: This is a dummy example. I have a data frame containing such 80 categories over continuous 100 days. An automatic summary like above one will reduce the effort.

Answer (score 0):

Pair-counting cluster evaluation measures show an easy way to tackle this problem.

Rather than looking at object-cluster assignments, which are unstable, these methods look at whether or not two objects are in the same cluster (that is called a "pair").

So you could check if these pairs change much over time, or not.

Since k-means is randomized, you may also want to run it several times for every time slice, as they may return different clusterings!

You could then say that e.g. series 1 is in the same cluster as series 2 in 90% of the results. etc.

Comment: Your explanation is correct and I want to calculate this percentage. But the external evaluation metrics mentioned at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis) does not seem to apply in my case as I do not have a ground truth (benchmark). This clustering is unsupervised. Your further insights might help me to dig further...

Comment: The same approach can be used to compare two results, from different time points. Most of these methods are symmetric, essentially they are a similarity measure for partitionings.

Comment: I rephrased my problem a little bit and got the answer at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40713096/3317829) stack overflow link