# Compute similarity percentage OR Compute correlation between more than 2 objects

Tags: r, machine-learning, statistics

Consider I have four objects (`a,b,c,d`), and I ask five persons to label them (category 1 or 2) according to their physical appearance or something else. The labels provided by five persons for these objects are shown as

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,1,2,1), b=c(1,2,2,1,1), c= c(2,1,2,2,2), d=c(1,2,1,2,1))
```

In tabular format,

```
 ---------
  a b c d
 ---------
  1 1 2 1
  2 2 1 2
  1 2 2 1
  2 1 2 2
  1 1 2 1
----------
```

Now I want to calculate the percentage of times a group of objects were given the same label (either 1 or 2). For example, objects a, b and d  were given the same label by 3 persons out of 5 persons. So its percentage is 3/5 (=60%). While as objects a and d were given same labels by all the people, so its percentage is 5/5 (=100%)

I can calculate this statistic manually, but in my original dataset, I have 50 such objects and the people are 30 and the labels are 4 (1,2,3, and 4). How can I compute such statistics for this bigger dataset automatically? Are there any existing packages/tools in `R` which can calculate such statistics?

Note: A group can be of any size. In the first example, a group consists of a,b and d while as second example group consists of a and d.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two tasks here: firstly, making a list of all the relevant combinations, and secondly, evaluating and aggregating rowwise similarity. `combn` can start the first task, but it takes a little massaging to arrange the results into a neat list. The second task could be handled with `prop.table`, but here it's simpler to calculate directly.

Here I've used `tidyverse` grammar (primarily `purrr`, which is helpful for handling lists), but convert into base if you like.

```
library(tidyverse)

map(2:length(df), ~combn(names(df), .x, simplify = FALSE)) %>%    # get combinations
    flatten() %>%    # eliminate nesting
    set_names(map_chr(., paste0, collapse = '')) %>%    # add useful names
    # subset df with combination, see if each row has only one unique value
    map(~apply(df[.x], 1, function(x){n_distinct(x) == 1})) %>% 
    map_dbl(~sum(.x) / length(.x))    # calculate TRUE proportion

##   ab   ac   ad   bc   bd   cd  abc  abd  acd  bcd abcd 
##  0.6  0.2  1.0  0.2  0.6  0.2  0.0  0.6  0.2  0.0  0.0
```

Comment: When I run the above code on my original data frame containing 40 objects (variables ) with ten observations, it never stops. Before the start, I had a disk space of 8GB, but during the run, a window pops and shows warning "Disk space full", and within some minutes my system hangs and crashes. Any better solution to make this fast and less memory consumable. It runs for 45 minutes before crashing

Comment: Well yeah, combinations get big quickly. For 40 variables, that's `sum(choose(40, 2:40))` = 1.099512e+12 combinations, each with 10 observations. You can calculate a subset at a time easily if you like, but it's probably more useful to look into clustering methods.

Comment: I parallelize the code on corei7 machine using `R parallel` package and then tried `choose(40,5)` in both serial code and the parallel code. To my surprise, parallelized code takes more time than the serial one. Any thoughts from your side..

Comment: It depends a lot on implementation. Parallelizing involves more computations (you're adding splitting and recombining) and more memory (if available), so speed is not a given. Really, though, these are problems that reward playing smarter, not harder, depending on what you're looking for. If you just want combinations with a match over, say, 75%, first run 40 choose 2, and then filter the larger combinations that include a high-performing small one. Better, just use an actual clustering algorithm, e.g. `plot(hclust(dist(t(df), method = 'manhattan') / nrow(df)))`

Answer (score 4):

If you have numeric ratings, you could use `diff` to check if you consistently have `0` difference between each rater:

```
f <- function(cols, data) {
  sum(colSums(diff(t(data[cols]))==0)==(length(cols)-1)) / nrow(data)
}
```

Results are as expected when applying the function to example groups:

```
f(c("a","b","d"), df)
#[1] 0.6
f(c("a","d"), df)
#[1] 1
```

Answer (score 2):

With base R functions you could do:

```
 groupVec = c("a","b","d")

 transDF = t(as.matrix(DF))

 subDF  = transDF[rownames(transDF) %in% groupVec,]
 subDF
   # [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
 # a    1    2    1    2    1
 # b    1    2    2    1    1
 # d    1    2    1    2    1

 #if length of unique values is 1, it implies match across all objects, count unique values/total columns = match pct
 match_pct = sum(sapply(as.data.frame(subDF), function(x)  sum(length(unique(x))==1) ))/ncol(subDF)
 match_pct
 # [1] 0.6
```

Wrapping it in a custom funtion:

```
 fn_matchPercent = function(groupVec =  c("a","d") ) {


 transDF = t(as.matrix(DF))

 subDF  = transDF[rownames(transDF) %in% groupVec,]

 match_pct = sum(sapply(as.data.frame(subDF), function(x)  sum(length(unique(x))==1) ))/ncol(subDF)


 outputDF = data.frame(groups = paste0(groupVec,collapse=",") ,match_pct = match_pct)

 return(outputDF)

 }

 fn_matchPercent(c("a","d"))
   # groups match_pct
 # 1    a,d         1
 fn_matchPercent(c("a","b","d"))
   # groups match_pct
 # 1  a,b,d       0.6
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
find.unanimous.percentage <- function(df, at.a.time) {
  cols <- as.data.frame(t(combn(names(df), at.a.time)))
  names(cols) <- paste('O', 1:at.a.time, sep='')
  cols$percent.unanimous <- 100*colMeans(apply(cols, 1, function(x) apply(df[x], 1, function(y) length(unique(y)) == 1)))
  return(cols)
}

find.unanimous.percentage(df, 2) # take 2 at a time

  O1 O2 percent.unanimous
1  a  b                60
2  a  c                20
3  a  d               100
4  b  c                20
5  b  d                60
6  c  d                20

find.unanimous.percentage(df, 3) # take 3 at a time

  O1 O2 O3 percent.unanimous
1  a  b  c                 0
2  a  b  d                60
3  a  c  d                20
4  b  c  d                 0

find.unanimous.percentage(df, 4)  

  O1 O2 O3 O4 percent.unanimous
1  a  b  c  d                 0
```

Answer (score 1):

### Clustering similarity metrics

It seems that you might want to calculate a substantially different (better?) metric than what you propose now, if your actual problem requires to evaluate various options of clustering the same data.

This http://cs.utsa.edu/~qitian/seminar/Spring11/03_11_11/IR2009.pdf is a good overview of the problem, but the BCubed precision/recall metrics are commonly used for similar problems in NLP (e.g http://alias-i.com/lingpipe/docs/api/com/aliasi/cluster/ClusterScore.html).

Comment: Yes, you got the problem right! I posted the same question at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40689434/3317829) stack overflow link. After reading the external cluster evaluation metrics as suggested, I found that those metrics require some reference/benchmark, which I don't have. I wonder how can I use those metrics. I know the current approach is not optimal. It is the worst case. Any further insights from your side might be helpful...

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. It works for your example and should hold for the extended case.

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,1,2,1), b=c(1,2,2,1,1), c= c(2,1,2,2,2), d=c(1,2,1,2,1))

# Find all unique combinations of the column names
group_pairs <- data.frame(t(combn(colnames(df), 2)))

# For each combination calculate the similarity
group_pairs$similarities <- apply(group_pairs, 1, function(x) {
  sum(df[x["X1"]] == df[x["X2"]])/nrow(df)
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort. It is easy to compute for a group consisting of a pair of objects, but how to scale it for groups with more than two objects like the group consisting of objects a, b and d is really hard.

Comment: Ah soz I misunderstood the question